# how to get the double-click-time in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

How I can get the duration in milliseconds that is valid for a DoubleClick in WPF. The same as in Windows Forms the `SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime`-property was.

Comment: Yes, use the Windows Forms class.  MouseDevice uses the same source of info.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [P/Invoke to call GetDoubleClickTime](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getdoubleclicktime) directly:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern uint GetDoubleClickTime();
```

This will return the number of milliseconds for a double click.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. Is there also a version without P/Invoke (and not windows forms)? I try to not use P/Invoke because I don't really know what the penalties in using it are (besides of restriction of code-execution).

Comment: @HCL: It's pretty much use windows forms, or use P/Invoke.  P/Invoke's a bit lighter-weight, since it's not adding any dependencies (except user32.dll, which is part of Windows).  There's no native WPF option.  [The Windows Forms class, btw, just uses P/Invoke to call the Windows API...]

Comment: +1, I just went through all of the InputManager/MouseDevice classes in WPF to double check and there appears to be no other way than P/Invoke or WinForms.