# Extend WPF Button Functionality

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I found a code on MSDN that suits my need, but I have a problem. ( [Here is the code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172533.aspx) )

There is a DoubleClickButton class that extends the normal button. The problem that I have is that I cannot use this class in xaml.

Here is the following error that I have: 
Invalid type: expected type is 'UIElement', actual type is 'DoubleClickButton'.

I tried to change in class to inherit the UIElement ( even the fact that the button is an UIElement ), tried also to leave as inheritance only the UIElement but no luck.

Any ideas, how can I use this new enhanced control in xaml?

Regards, 
Danut

Comment: You are trying to use `winforms` control in `wpf`. For this you will need to *host* it (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761.aspx)). The better idea would be to create native wpf control.

Comment: Does your definition still look like this: `public class DoubleClickButton : System.Windows.Forms.Button`. If so, inherit from WPF Button instead.

Comment: Your link is using forms

Comment: Seems that I missed that. Changed to use the System.Windows.Controls.Button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slightly more WPF version:

```
public class DoubleClickButton : System.Windows.Controls.Button
{

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetDoubleClickTime();
    // Note that the DoubleClickTime property gets 
    // the maximum number of milliseconds allowed between 
    // mouse clicks for a double-click to be valid.
    int previousClick = (int)GetDoubleClickTime();

    public event EventHandler DoubleClick;

    protected override void OnClick()
    {
        int now = System.Environment.TickCount;

        // A double-click is detected if the the time elapsed
        // since the last click is within DoubleClickTime.
        if (now - previousClick <= (int)GetDoubleClickTime())
        {
            // Raise the DoubleClick event.
            if (DoubleClick != null)
                DoubleClick(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        // Set previousClick to now so that 
        // subsequent double-clicks can be detected.
        previousClick = now;
        base.OnClick();
    }

    // Event handling code for the DoubleClick event.
    protected virtual void OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DoubleClick != null)
            DoubleClick(this, e);
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Replaced SystemInformation with GetDoubleClickTime(), thanks to Andreas Niedermair.

**EDIT2** Example styling in XAML.

```
<local:DoubleClickButton Content="Test" DoubleClick="DoubleClickButton_OnDoubleClick">
    <local:DoubleClickButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:DoubleClickButton}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </local:DoubleClickButton.Style>
</local:DoubleClickButton>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662514/how-to-get-the-double-click-time-in-wpf

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. It works pretty well, but I still have a problem. If I use this code, even the fact that this custom button inherits the System.Controls.Button I`m not able to style it. This error pops up: The attachable property 'Style' was not found in type 'DoubleClickButton'.

Comment: @Rock3rRullz: I have added an example of a `Style`.