# How to get double click interval on MacOS

Tags: c#, macos, double-click, nsevent

We're developing a Unity editor extension. For that we need to know the double click interval of the OS.
On windows you can get this with an external call like so
([how to get the double-click-time in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662514/how-to-get-the-double-click-time-in-wpf)):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern uint GetDoubleClickTime();
```

This obviously doesn't work on MacOS. Is there something similar?
We found the nsevent doubleClickInterval (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1528384-doubleclickinterval) which seems to be the equivalent on Mac, but how to call this from .NET?

Any hints are greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You can always implement the functionality yourself - by considering times between first and second click. Other option is to find similar functionality in IOS libraries and call those - I found [some docs about this but for Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/walkthrough?tabs=windows).